# Locate complete and accurate Azure REST API 'apiVersion' strings?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to check the existence of resources throughout my subscription, but it seems like 50% of the resources expect a different `apiVersion` to the others.

I find it weird that Azure isn't consistent across the board with their apiVersions, but does anyone have or know of a list of the resource providers "api versions" that are current accurate and up to date?

Answer (score 1):

The only truely reliable place I have found is the arm schemas in github:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas

I clone the repo then do a findstr or similar to find whatever the latest folder is.

Ed

Comment: I've actually found a way to do this programmatically in C# using the same endpoints that powershell uses. It's a massive pain but I'll post the answer a bit later!

Thank you for the recommendation though.